# If $X_i = \varnothing$ for some $i$, then $\prod_i X_i = \varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of sets. Show that if $X_i=\emptyset$ for some $i\in I$ then $\prod\limits_{i\in I}X_i=\emptyset$.

We know that $A\times \emptyset = \emptyset$. So the result holds. However I was given this definition:

> Let $\{X_j\}_{j\in J}$ be a family of sets. The cartesian product of this family is $\prod\limits_{j\in J}X_j$, which is the set of all the functions $x:J\longrightarrow \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}X_j$ such that $x(j)\in X_j$ for every $j\in J$.

My question is, is there a way to show the first statement including info. from the definition? I thought about that since  there is a $i$ such that $X_i=\emptyset$, then this implies that there is a $x(i)\notin X_i$. Then the functions mentioned in the definition do not exist and therefore $\prod\limits_{i\in I}X_i=\emptyset$. I'm doubting about my result.

Comment: Your argument is correct. If there were some $x\in\prod_{j\in J}X_j$, then we’d have $x(i)\in X_i=\varnothing$, which is impossible. Therefore no such $x$ exists, and $\prod_{j\in J}X_j=\varnothing$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott do you suggest deleting this question?

Comment: That’s entirely up to you. If you leave it, I’ll convert my comment to an answer, so that the question doesn’t go unanswered, but you could just as well delete it if you’re satisfied with the comment.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm satisfied, however the question might be useful for someone in the future.

Comment: Okay; I’ll write up a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct. If there were some $x\in\prod_{j\in J}X_j$, then we’d have $x(i)\in X_i=\varnothing$, which is clearly impossible. Thus, no such $x$ can exist, and it must be the case that $\prod_{j\in J}X_j=\varnothing$.

Comment: If $J\neq\emptyset$ and $\cup_{j\in J} X_j=\emptyset$ then no functions $J\rightarrow\cup_{j\in J}X_j$ exists (confirming this answer). But things are different if $J=\emptyset$. Then by definition $\cup_{j\in J} X_j=\emptyset$ and there is exactly one such function. So I think that is a (unique) exception.

Comment: @drhab: Note that the hypothesis is that $X_i=\varnothing$ for some $i\in J$, so we know that $J\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Ah, yes. I overlooked. I thought that $X_i$ was supposed to be empty for each $i$ (in stead of "some").